# Unable to access dynamodb from nodejs code through lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have been trying to test this from lambda but unable to proceed.

```
    var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");

    var dynamoDBConfiguration = {
        "accessKeyId": "useraccess",
        "secretAccessKey": "usersecretkey",
        "region": "us-east-1"
      };
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfiguration);
    var promisify = require("es6-promisify");
    var dynClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({"region":"us-east-  
    1"});


    //convert callback style functions to promises
    const dbGet = promisify(dynClient.get,dynClient);
    const dbPut = promisify(dynClient.put,dynClient);
    const dbDelete = promisify(dynClient.delete,dynClient);


    var startStateHandlers = (GAME_STATES.STARt, {
        "StartGame": function (isNewGame,context) {

            const dynamoParams = {
                TableName: "Userdata",
                Key: {
                  "UserId":"test"
                }
              }

          dbGet(dynamoParams)
                .then(data => {
                  console.log('Get user succeeded', data);
                  const userId = data.UserId;

                  if (userId != null) {                
                    console.log(data.UserName);                
                  }
                  else {
                    // no match, add the user
                    return dbPut(dynamoParams);
                  }
                })
                .then(data => {
                  console.log('Add user succeeded', data);              
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.error(err);
                });

               this.emit(":tell", speechOutput, speechOutput);
        }
    });
    var handlers = {    
        "LaunchRequest": function () {
            var speechOutput = "hello";
            this.emit(":tell", speechOutput, speechOutput);
        }
    };
    var handler = (function () {
        function handler(event, context, callback) {
            var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
            alexa.appId = "appid";     

            alexa.registerHandlers(handlers, startStateHandlers);
            alexa.execute();
        }
        return handler;
    })();
    exports.handler = handler;
```

It doesnt throw any error in the lamda logs and not able to see any log in Cloudwatch. It just executes the other lines of code.

I have attached all permission policy to the user and setup the lamda function as lambda_dynamo.

Unable to understand what is the issue with it.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamoDBConfiguration = {
   "accessKeyId": "useraccess",
   "secretAccessKey": "usersecretkey",
   "region": "us-east-1"
};
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// update the AWS.Config global configuration object
AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfiguration)
// Create DynamoDB document client
var dynClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
```

Comment: sorry, I missed that line while editing. I have that in the code but it didn't change anything